# GSA crawl vs content feed which way is better approach

Tags: google-search-appliance

I have been ruuning GSA with content crawling for some good time and have always seen issues with search results, the expected results are never there or found of wrong places, this could be due to wrong config or something else. However it has been working.

Due to last update of website, the sorting of results is now in a mess and I am unable to find a way out of it. The pattern of last modified date (meta tag) is not differnt from new pages, I guess due to this there is great inconsistency of content, the search always start from old content no matter i sort of date or relevency.

I am thinking to switch to content feed and feed all content from database to GSA using content feed. But want to know the opinion is this is better approach or Crawl is still a better option...

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell GSA which date to use for sorting the results.
By default,GSA inspects "Last-Modified" response header(While crawling the web contents) to update sort date  i.e `<FS name="date" value="YYYY-MM-DD">`. If your application is not sending the "Last-Modified" response header, then you have to configure "Document Dates" on GSA admin console. It will help GSA to extract the date from your metadata and update FS date accordingly.

you can read about document dates configuration [here](http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/72/admin_console_help/crawl_sort.html)

Regarding your question on which is better web crawl or content feed,
Feeds are meant for crawling documents which needs special handling. 
[Read this](http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/70/gsa_doc_set/feedsguide/feedsguide.html#1074265) to understand when/why to use feeds.If your GSA can crawl content thru web, you should choose to go with web crawl.

Regards,

Mohan.